# Should I be looking closely at vendor items at higher difficulties?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been trained by earlier versions of Diablo to consider vendor items basically worthless once you start finding your own gear.  But since I've noticed that a number of players showing their Inferno gear have blue items, it occurs to me that this might be a mistake.  Is it possible for vendors to have items that are a high enough level to generate very high stats (like +160 to primary) that would be worthwhile for a higher level character?  Or should I continue to ignore them (except in the rare case where they have a yellow for sale)?

Comment: I've seen a few _relatively_ good items, nothing exceptional, but a sidegrade here or there at level 60. This is in act 1 inferno though, so my gear's not the greatest yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that they can be useful, especially when you first transition to a higher difficulty.

Comment: I've also found some decent +dmg rings and amulets on all difficulties, so I think it's worthing looking at the vendor inventory once in a while. Though once you hit lvl 60 I doubt they'll have anything worthwhile

Answer (score 2):

If you are buying items you will probalby find cheaper and better from the AH. I prefer to get upgrades from killing where possible as it give you some reason to explore the dungeons that arn't part of the main quest line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you absolutely should - not just for yourself on the occasion a weapon with decent DPS might appear, but also for the times when vendors stock magic rings or gloves with high primary stats and boosted Attack Speed. Not only are these great for personal use, but they're also often sellable on the auction house for more than their vendor cost.

Comment: No, they're not sellable. No one is buying blue low level rings.

Answer (score 0):

I always take a quick look if I am going past them anyways..
Just yesterday on Inferno act 1 I found a great new amulet! Worked great for my Monk.

Comment: It would probably be good if you posted the stats of the amulet so that people get an idea of what quality level it is. If it's just a 90 dex, 40 vit amulet, it's not that awesome.

Comment: Ill add later tonight, im at work :-(

Comment: @JoshuaDudash No follow-up?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely look at the AH first, where you can easily sort by buyout and pick item traits you want.  Often you'll be able to find something much faster, fits your build exactly, and cheaper than checking out vendors.

Having said that, magic find items are horribly over priced right now so I always check out the vendors (at least on inferno) to try and find upgrades for that, especially MF amulets and rings.